# can i use fbml without fb connect?

Tags: facebook

Can i use fbml multiple friend selector tag without using F connect. I mean i have the offline session keys for users.

Would like to show multiple friends selector form by using the session keys i have. But i have no idea how to set the session.

Is there any way??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the set_user method from Facebook API

Here's a sample using the php library

```
$facebook = new Facebook(API_KEY, API_SECRET);
$facebook->set_user($user_id, $session_key);
```